# dispatch_queue_t object access rules

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm a bit confused on the rules for dispatch_queues.

Let's say I create a queue like this:

```
_captureSessionQueue = dispatch_queue_create("capture_session_queue", NULL);
```

and I initialize my `AVCaptureSession` like this:

```
dispatch_async(_captureSessionQueue, ^{
      self.captureSession = [self createCaptureSession];
});
```

My question is, am I now absolutely *required* to use

`dispatch_async(_captureSessionQueue, ^{...})`

whenever I want to access the `captureSession` object?

For example, is this bad?

(notice I use the main queue here, not the session queue)

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.captureSession addInput:input];  
})
```

Must I do

```
dispatch_async(_captureSessionQueue, ^{
    [self.captureSession addInput:input];  
})
```

or is it optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends entirely on the thread safety of the accessed object(s).

#### Is it thread safe?

Use it in any queue you like.

#### Is it almost thread safe (i.e. can be accessed from different threads, but not simultaneously)?

You can use it from different threads, but you have to synchronise the access

#### Is it main/created thread only?

Don't use it from another queue.

[This Friday Q&A](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-01-09.html) by Mike Ash is a good read on the topic. There is also an [(incomplete) list](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafetySummary/ThreadSafetySummary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH12-SW1) in the Apple Threading Programming Guide.

Answer (score 1):

The real question is why you are saying this:

```
dispatch_async(_captureSessionQueue, ^{
      self.captureSession = [self createCaptureSession];
});
```

Is this because `[self createCaptureSession]` is time-consuming? Then create it in a background thread, but *assign it to `self.captureSession` on the main thread*. This will make your life much easier later. Basically, if all your access to `self.captureSession` is on the main thread, that access will be thread-safe (and easy).

So, I would write, perhaps (if I understood why we are using a background thread in the first place):

```
dispatch_async(_captureSessionQueue, ^{
      AVCaptureSession* sess = [self createCaptureSession];
      dispatch_asynch(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
          self.captureSession = sess;
      });
});
```

Talking to a property of `self` on a background thread seems to me to be a recipe for confusion and possible disaster. A huge benefit of GCD is that you get to avoid that sort of thing, because instead you can just pass stuff down from thread to thread (as in my code above).

Comment: That protects the `captureSession` property, but doesn't help if `AVCaptureSession` is not thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

You created a serial queue, _captureSessionQueue. You can use that queue to guarantee that all blocks dispatched to that queue will be executed one after the other, like on the main queue, but on a background thread, unlike the main queue.

Dispatching on the serial queue means it is guaranteed that any previous calls dispatched to the queue have finished, which often makes things easy and makes it unnecessary to synchronize. For example, anything dispatched to the _captureSessionQueue after the block that set self.captureSession will find that self.captureSession has been initialised.

However, if you want to use self.captureSession on another thread, that's fine. You just don't have the guarantees that you get from a serial queue.